# Convenient way to have selected files shown in the beginning of file lists in file managers?

Tags: filenames, sort, special-characters, file-manager

In Windows if one wishes certain file (or directory) to be shown in the beginning of file lists in a file manager (no matter which one, really), one may choose to put the underscore character in the first position of the file name. Sometimes, this solution is convenient, albeit not very elegant. It works for me.

On the other hand, Linux seems to ignore such underscore signs in front of file names (I am talking here about file sorting only, of course).

Is there any way to customise Linux to respect such leading underscores while sorting? If no, what would you advise to achieve that effect on Linux (I use Lubuntu, if it matters, but this question is not about specific flavour, I trust) apart from reverting to some abominable constructions such as «aaa_» an so on?

Comment: Linux is just a kernel. Its `getdents()` system call will return directory entries in an unspecified order. It's applications that sort the list for display to the user for convenience. How they do it depends on the application itself, but generally they do it in locale collation order, and so depends on the locale. That's independent  of the kernel.

Comment: What file manager is this for? What is the default file manager on Lubuntu? Also, how is `aaa_` more abominable than `_`? I mean, both are simply adding extra characters to a name to affect how the name is sorted, there's no magic.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Well, you certainly know more about this stuff than I do. I have tested four file managers (Double commander, PCmanFX, Nautilus  and Dolphin) and they all share this feature (disregarding the leading underscore). It is hard to believe they were all programmed to behave in the same way (after all, AFAIK, they were written by different people). I thought there was some standard, some shared components or something. As for locale, well, it is standard American locale.

Comment: Yes, they will likely use a standard API (`strcoll()`) to compare the strings. `strcoll()` is part of the C library, it has nothing to do with Linux. The libc on Ubuntu will be GNU one. In a `en_US.UTF-8` locale, `_` would have an undefined primary weight in the collation algorithm, and be ignored unless the next weights are being used. For those applications that use collation order, you'll need to use a prefix with a defined primary weight in your locale and that sorts before the other characters your file names have.

Comment: @terdon The default file manager in Lubuntu is PCmanFM (but I tried a few manager as well, please see my comment above). I am not saying the stuff like `aaa_` does not work. It surely does. In fact this is what I am using now. I just don't like it and I would be more satisfied with single extra character in stead of four. Maybe, it makes no difference to you. It is matter of taste and habits, I presume. That explains the word «convenient» in the topics' header (of course, every one has his own idea about what convenient is).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Okay, thank you, the picture is clearer now. One last question. Do you know if there are any ways to add weight to the underscore? I mean without recompiling a lot of code or something which is clearly beyond my modest capabilities. I appreciate your time, so if you could point me to some resources which explain how this weighting and collation ordering works, that would be enough.

Comment: @S.N., yes you could define a new locale like `en_US.UTF-8@underscore` where you tweak the collation order. That sounds like a lot of effort for little benefit. Using a `0` prefix is a common approach for this kind of thing. See the `00README` you'll find here and there.

Answer (score 0):

In C local `_` is between upper and lower case. In other locals it will vary.
I have been using a `+` for years. As far as I can remember, it sorts to the top. (Can't test now, as at work using MS).